# Bikepacking from Germany to Netherlands during covid-19 pandemic

Tags: germany, netherlands, covid-19, bicycles, indonesian-citizens

I'm planning to cycle from Berlin to Utrecht Netherlands around end of this month. The question is, is it safe to travel there. Will I get any restriction going there ? I'm an Indonesian having work permit visa at the moment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the situation around the pandemic changes rapidly, and even an answer that could be correct today is likely to be out of date tomorrow.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica and others: note that this was migrated from the Bicycles SE site. If the poster plans to bikepack (i.e. carry camping equipment on your bicycle), then it may be possible to avoid a lot of contact with people. However, many touring cyclists may stay in hotels overnight rather than camp. Again, I'd urge the OP to clarify their travel plans and what aspects of safety they are asking about. The issue of crossing borders should be squarely on topic for this SE site, or at least we hoped so when we voted to migrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it safe to travel there.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019%E2%80%9320_coronavirus_pandemic_by_country_and_territory and decide by yourself.

> Will I get any restriction going there?

According to https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/NLD, you can go from Berlin to Utrecht Netherlands, but:

> Travellers from EU and Schengen countries can travel in and out of the Netherlands. Tourists must reserve their holiday accommodation before they travel to the Netherlands. You may be stopped at the border if you don’t have a valid reservation. Dutch advice and rules to combat the spread of COVID-19 must be followed.

Also from https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/NLD:

> May I freely move within this country? YES. Use public transport for essential travel only. You must wear a non-medical face mask when using public transport. To get around, use your own vehicle, rent a bike or take a taxi.

https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/DEU:

> May I freely move within this country? YES

Comment: Thanks a lot ! this information is what I need